# Creating a random method that will add objects into a stack with random index

Tags: java, random, stack

Here is small sample:

```
Stack<String> myStack = new Stack<String>();
myStack.add("Cat");
myStack.add("Dog");
myStack.add("Bird");
myStack.add("Elephant");
```

So basically `myStack` object has 4 strings. I would like to insert 3 more Strings into `myStack` with a RANDOM index. Usually when i put a new String using `myStack.add();` the new input will be assigned at the top(Index 0) which I don't want it to be in this case. I would like it to be randomly put in a random index. What is the solution for this?

Comment: A stack is usually used for push and pop operations. You're baasically looking for a list. Have a look at `ArrayList`, it provides methods to add elements at specified indexes and shifts the rest of the list back.

Comment: Stack **does not** allow random access.  If you need to emulate it you will have to do several pops and store results outside the stack, then push your new value, and then re-push the saved ones.

Comment: Thanks. I think i misread the spec. I didn't have to put the strings into a Stack with random index. :P

Comment: ? So does that mean your question is not valid anymore / can be closed?

Comment: Actually someone has a good suggestion and I think I have figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since Stack is a subclass of Vector you can do it like this

```
<E> void addRandom(Stack<E> stack, E e) {
    stack.add((int) (Math.random() * (stack.size() + 1)), e);
}
```

or make a custom class

```
class RandomStack<E> extends Stack<E> {

    void addRandom(E e) {
        add((int) (Math.random() * (size() + 1)), e);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is helpful for me. I think it works the way I want it to be. Thanks :P